# method not found may be due to parameters format

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I'm writing an apex class that gets params from my js. and here is my code piece.

```
action.setParams({
  "mapOfFields": {
    "enf_income_witholdings__x": {
      ["tot_amt_to_whld__c","past_due_chld_supt_amt__c"]
    }
  }
})
```

And in my apex, I take it as

```
public static void getData(Map<String, List<String>> mapOfFields)
```

But it says that the action couldn't be found, where an I going wrong?

Comment: Did you try calling the parameter `mapOfFields`?

Comment: Yes, that was my call. apologies, I pasted some test code here.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` denotes an object, which must be initialized in `{ key: value }` pairs. As such, it should be:

```
action.setParams({
  "mapOfFields": {
    "enf_income_witholdings__x": { "prop_name": 
      ["tot_amt_to_whld__c","past_due_chld_supt_amt__c"]
    }
  }
})
```

Or, more generically:

```
{ "paramName": { "mapKey1": [ "value1","value2" ], "mapKey2": [ "value3" ] } }
```